# Are private GIT repositories available for Microsoft TFS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

We are using Visual Studio TFS (seems like it is renamed to Azuredevops, isn't it?)
Is it possible to create there a private git repository?

I have checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=vsts and there is some authentication.

How to set up privacy for git repository on vsts?

Comment: A man here stated that there can be created only public repositories on Microsoft remote source control server. But I want to prove he is not correct

Comment: That was available since the first day TFS Online was released. If you google for `TFS Private Repos` one of the first results is the [landing page itself](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/repos/) whose title is `Get unlimited, cloud-hosted private Git repos for your project`. Unlike other providers, TFS charges by named users, not number of private repos. You can have hundreds of repos as long as you don't have more than 5 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the new brand name for VSTS is Azure DevOps.

To create a private repository the project admin can hide the repository from the users who are handling the project by following this :

Goto Repositories->Select Repo(Make sure that the user(s) that need to restricted are added to the project as members as well as on repo) -> Select user -> Set Read To Deny

[image: Private Repo]

UPDATE:

To make a repo private from outside world u can just create the project as private. The repository is not segregated, it is part of the project.
At repo level you can hide repo to make them private as shown above.

[image: Private Project]

Comment: The concern is to make repository unavailable to some random unauthorized visitor from big Internet

Comment: @IvanP. the service's site [explains that yes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/repos/), they do provide private repos and charge by the number of users, not repos. That's how TFS Online works for several years now

Comment: @IvanP. try as above, Let me know if it does not work.